# Do I need full text search and if so how to implement full text search on sql2000?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, sql-server-2000, full-text-search

I'm using Linq2Sql for my asp.net mvc project and so far it has worked out just great.
Now however I need to implement a "key word search" that searches for x key words over about 20 fields spread over 10 joined tables that are joined with a maximum depth of 3 levels.
The linq function is really simpel, but the generated query is just too slow (about 25 secs for 2 words). I implemented some caching, but just caching is not gonna cut it.
I tried with a stored procedure myself and improved it really slightly, but the optimalizations were very limited.

Now I read up on full text searching and if I'm getting it right, this looks like what I'm needing. Could anyone cofirm this?
The system needs to run on SQL2000. If FTS is what I'm needing, could anybody help me on how to set it up? Is it built in in SQL2000? Do I need other libraries/services for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [SQL Server 2000 Full-Text Search Deployment white paper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323739), but I would only use full text search where I was searching columns with large text blocks.

Comment: So you do agree that this would be the thing I need?